# Possible Web Framework to Use in Existing Application

Tags: javascript, java, spring, web, frameworks

I work for a medium sized company that has an application used by a few thousand people and is built primarily with HTML,Javascript, aspx, xml, xsl, and runs on IE 11. This application is proprietary and not designed in house but we have access to the code for possible modifications and its just sitting out there on the server(s). A new project has come down the pipline for an enhancement\adjustment to be made to a particular area of the application and I'm wondering what kind of web framework I could use to do this work. I am really just needing to call an enterprise service and get data back, display it, and that's about it, so its not incredibly hard. I am worried though about how to integrate it with the existing application.

I am not sure how this scenario would go:

User navigates to page A inputs data, I want that data to go to a controller or something I built, fetch info and send it back to page A. I was thinking of using Spring MVC but not sure. Any feed back or suggestions would be greatly appreciated! I know this question doesn't include code, so please don't hate me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

From a very high point of view and with no knowledge about any specific requirement.

If you have already an application developed in ASP.NET, it's better that you continue the development of the new module of the application on the same platform.

If you want to develop a new module (actually a new web app) that looks like the old application but with a totally different platform like Spring MVC (could use any other), you can reuse the existing css styles and databases.

For integration purpose you could modify the original application in the menu(or links) that redirects you to the new module and implement a single sign on server (this will required work on both applications) to made the transitions smoothly between both applications (something like a portal style). Note that they will have a different context application path.

Comment: Hey, thanks very much for your feed back its much appreciated. After thinking a bit more I would agree with your thoughts. Let's say the existing app is hosted in IIS. If I used spring MVC, I could use the existing CSS files, and would need to deploy a WAR file for consumption. This would mean that apache Tomcat would need to run on the server as well. This would mean that calling this other module\page within the existing app would be navigating to my specific web app. I see what you're saying, it makes perfect sense.

Comment: Also, there may be a conflict with having a site hosted by IIS but trying to make a call to a web page hosted via apache Tomcat. Hmmmm, I hadn't thought of this.